# When I insert 60,000 rows to a newly created table. This error appears. String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to insert data to a newly created table. It gives me an error,

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 3 String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been terminated.

This is the script to create the table. The datatypes are based from the source tables and nothing has been changed.

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ODSCustomerContact]')
            AND type IN (N'U')
        )
    DROP TABLE [ODSCustomerContact]
GO

CREATE TABLE ODSCustomerContact (
    CustomerContactInt INT NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    ContactFirstName NVARCHAR(60) NULL,
    ContactLastName NVARCHAR(60) NULL,
    Position NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Phone NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    MobilePhone NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    EmailAddress NVARCHAR(30) NULL
    )
```

When I try to insert the error appears.

```
INSERT INTO sec_ods.dbo.ODSCustomerContact
SELECT d.SoldToShortName AS Clientname,
    e.FirstName AS Contact_FirstName,
    e.LastName AS Contact_LastName,
    e.Position,
    e.Phone,
    e.MobilePhone,
    e.EmailAddr AS EmailAdress
FROM projectrule d
LEFT JOIN BusinessEntityAssociation BEA
    ON d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID
LEFT JOIN BusinessEntityContact e
    ON e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID
WHERE d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
```

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 3 String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The error is related to the data that you are trying to insert, you should have some data that is biger that your columns table, like a client name that has more that 30 charachter.

Comment: I mean really, error writers should just replace all their descriptive error messages with "WRONG!" The same number of Stack Overflow questions would result.

Answer (score 3):

One of the columns in the destination table does not accept the same data-length as the source table.

You should probably generate the destination table by scripting the source table. Otherwise you might end up in a situation like this, where the source column Phone might be defined as `varchar(50)`, but the destination table has it defined as `varchar(30)`.

Thus, there's a risk for data loss, and this error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you identify the column with overflowing data. based on that you can tune your table creation script

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(d.SoldToShortName)) AS Clientname,
    MAX(LEN(e.FirstName)) AS Contact_FirstName,
    MAX(LEN(e.LastName)) AS Contact_LastName,
    MAX(LEN(e.Position)) AS Position,
    MAX(LEN(e.Phone)) AS Phone,
    MAX(LEN(e.MobilePhone)) AS MobilePhone,
    MAX(LEN(e.EmailAddr)) AS EmailAddr
FROM projectrule d
LEFT JOIN BusinessEntityAssociation BEA
    ON d.soldtoID = BEA.customerID
LEFT JOIN BusinessEntityContact e
    ON e.BusinessEntityID = BEA.BusinessEntityID
WHERE d.SoldToShortName IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually encountered when inserting a record in a `table` where one of the columns is a `VARCHAR or CHAR` data type and the length of the value being **inserted is longer than the length of the column**.

So, try to MAXIMIZE the length of column, or try to restrict the input field length.